# How to yank while in visual mode without showing message?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode, visual-block, message, linewise-visual

When I'm in visual mode and I yank the selection (which has at least 3 lines), messages like these are shown:

> 4 lines yanked

> block of 4 lines yanked

How can I suppress this so it won't appear in `:messages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this message is triggered when the number of lines you copy exceed the `report` setting that is set by default to 2

The following command should solve your problem:

```
:set report=100000
```

Slightly more information with `:help report`